# Activity Coefficients from Electrode Potentials

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

Lets say we want the activity coefficient of $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ ions in solution. Would we simply setup one half cell of a $\ce{Cu}$ electrode in a known concentration of $\ce{CuSO4}$ and then connect this to a Standard Hydrogen Electrode.

Using the standard electrode potential of the reaction $\ce{Cu^{2+} + 2e-  ->  Cu}$  and the Nernst equation could we determine the activity coefficient of $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ ions ?

Is this all I would need to do ?

Comment: You would not be able to easily separate the activity coefficients of the anion and cation using this method.

Comment: You will probably have to do a lot of concentration dependent cross measurements involving a huge set of different ions not only copper. You should also rather use Ag/AgCl electrode.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of 'yes', sort of 'no'.  Consider the following points:

1. Activity coefficients are notorious for changing with $\mathrm{p}\ce{H}$, ionic strength, and concentration (among other things).  You might measure the the activity coefficient of $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ in a $0.7~\mathrm{M}$ $\ce{CuSO4}$ solution and get one value, but try to measure the same thing in a low $\mathrm{p}\ce{H}$ and $1~\mathrm{\mu M}$ $\ce{CuCl2}$ solution and you may get a completely different value.  In practice, people usually end up measuring activity coefficients across a range of conditions that are relevant to their specific use-case.
2. The Standard Hydrogen Electrode is a theoretical device; and actually constructing something similar is difficult.  In practice, you would just want to use a commercially available double-junction silver-silver chloride or saturated calomel electrode. The potentials of those two are well-known and fairly stable.

See Chapter 2 of "Electrochemical Methods" 2nd Ed, by Bard and Faulkner for more information.